# Argument of type 'type' is not iterable.How?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append

```
money = 0
day = 1
items = []


def gameplay():
    global items
    global money
    global day
    energy = 10
    work = 0
    while True:
        print("Type 'help' for assistance")
        play = str(input("-> ")).strip()
        if play.lower() == "help":
            print("""
Type :   To :                                         Cost:
'Work'    Get Money (only once then next day)          5 Energy
'Mall'    Buy Stuff                                    5 Energy
'Items'   Check Inventory                              N/A
'Money'   Check Balance Of Money                       N/A
'Energy'  Check Balance Of Energy                      N/A
'Day'     Check your day, day 1 , day 2 etc.           N/A
'Done'    End Your Day                                 N/A    """)
        elif play.lower() == "work":
            if work == 1:
                print("You have already worked!")
            else:
                energy -= 5
                print("Working......")
                money += 5
                work += 1
                print("You now have $%s and %s Energy" % (money, energy))
        elif play.lower() == "mall":
            energy -= 5
            while True:
                print("What do you want to do?")
                print("""
Type :   To:                                     Cost:
Coffee   Buy Normal Coffee : +2 energy next day   $4
Lottery  Buy A Lottery Ticket (per day)           $10
Money    Check Balance Of Money                   N/A
Energy   Check Balance Of Energy                  N/A
Items    Check Your Inventory                     N/A
Exit     Exit the shopping mall                   N/A
                """)
                mall = input("-> ").strip()
                if mall.lower() == "coffee":
                    if "coffee" in list:
                        print("You have already bought a cup of coffee!")
                    elif money < 4:
                        print("You don't have enough money!")
                    else:
                        print("You bought a coffee")
                        items.append("coffee")
                        print(items)
                if mall.lower() == "lottery":
                    if "Lottery Ticket" in list:
                        print("You have already bought a ticket! Try again next day!")
                    lot = random.randint(1, 20)
                    jack = random.randint(100, 1000)
                    while True:
                        if money < 10:
                            print("You don't have enough money!")
                            break
                        else:
                            list.append("Lottery Ticket")
                            money -= 10
                            print("Choose a number between 1 to 20")
                            try:
                                lotg = int(input("-> "))
                                if lotg == lot:
                                    print("Congratulations you have won $%s" % (jack))
                                    money += jack
                                    break
                                elif lotg != lot:
                                    print("Sorry but you lost! Good luck Next Time")
                                    break
                            except ValueError:
                                print("Please Type A Number")
                elif mall.lower() == "money":
                    print("You currently have $%s" % (money))
                elif mall.lower() == "energy":
                    print("You currently have %s" % (energy))
                elif mall.lower() == "items":
                    print("These are your following items:")
                    print(items)
                elif mall.lower() == "exit":
                    print("Exiting mall......")
                    break
        elif play.lower() == "items":
            print("These are your following items:")
            print(items)
        elif play.lower() == "money":
            print("You currently have $%s" % (money))
        elif play.lower() == "energy":
            print("You currently have %s" % (energy))
        elif play.lower() == "day" :
            print("Its Day %s " % (day))
        elif play.lower() == "done":
            while True:
                print("Are You Sure?")
                sure = str(input("-> "))
                if sure.lower() not in ["yes","no"]:
                    print("Please Type Yes Or No ")
                elif sure.lower() == "yes":
                    print("Going Home For Next Day........")
                    home()
                elif sure.lower() == "no":
                    print("Okay!")
                    break


def noenergy():
    print("You don't have enough energy to do that")

def home():
    print("You are at home..")
gameplay()
```

It sometimes shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/scratches/scratch_718.py", line 120, in <module>
    gameplay()
  File "/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.1/scratches/scratch_718.py", line 50, in gameplay
    if "coffee" in list:
TypeError: argument of type 'type' is not iterable
```

when i test it in this order

1. input -> mall
2. input -> coffee
3. The error message should pop up

Tried to change the while loop part to a for loop but , still the same and I can't find any answers on a single website

Why is this happening? The loop? The list? The input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is not a variable containing a list, it's the *type* (hence the error message) of list objects.

It looks like you meant to use the variable `items` which is a list and forgot or got confused.

Comment: what do you mean by the type?

Comment: @cloroxide you can google "python type" if you want to learn more, the point now is that everywhere you use `list` in your program, you shouldn't be.

Comment: what should i use? when i google "python type" , it just shows python type() function.

Comment: @cloroxide you don't need to use anything that has to do with types. You want to use a list, use a list. You've already created one and used it several times. `list` is not a list.

Comment: you said i created a list and used it several times, but you said list is not a list, then how? can you give me an example of a solution?

Comment: @cloroxide `items` is a list.